# Verilog ring counter with skips

Tags: verilog, counter

I want to try a counter starting from 0 to 12. It can be a simple counter.

```
always @(posedge clock) begin
        count <= count+1;
        if (count == 4'd12) begin
        counter <= 0;
        end
end
```

But my task needs skip counting. For example, when skip is 4, count 0-5-10-15-20-25-30, because it's a 4bits counter it should be continue counting as 0-5-10-2-7-12. This skip count can be any number between 0 and 11. How to modify the simple verilog code according to my task?

Comment: Why are you using a blocking assignment in a sequential always@?

Comment: I'm new in Verilog. I use VHDL. How it should be?

Comment: Perhaps read [this page](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/programmable/quartushelp/13.0/mergedProjects/hdl/vlog/vlog_pro_counters.htm) for some example cases. Or [this page](https://class.ece.uw.edu/371/peckol/doc/Always@.pdf) for remedial education.

Comment: Oh sorry it should be <= instead of =.

Comment: But, the question is a bit different. If it will be exact 4 bits counter it can work by itself. How to calculate 10-2 transition when skip is equal 4?

Comment: I got "blocking assignment" easily, thank you.

Comment: When does the 'if' statement execute relative to the "count+1" statement? Do you think it must *follow*? Or do you think it is takes place at the same moment? In short, why don't you start with the compare and choose either to increment or else set a value? I'd like to know about your mental model. What is going on in your head relative to the code you see there?

Comment: If i understand correctly, you mean the code will be if(count == 12) else count+1, right?

Comment: But the problem is; if i increment the value by 5 when it is 10, it doesn't touch it's limit value(e.g. 12), it will overflow just like 4 bits counter not just like a limited counter(up to 12). Please warn me, if the question is not very clear.

Comment: Just your sureness, i know about registers and assignments will occur at the end of the clock cycle.

Comment: Also, i can't reset the counter to zero. If it bigger than 12, residual should be added to zero.

Comment: Why not something [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E3D0r.png)?

Comment: When skip is equal to 4, 0-5-10 next won't be equal 12.

Comment: I can't say that I fully understand your question. You haven't been detailed enough for me in it. So I have to back off at this point until more arrives from you or else someone else clarifies things for me.

Comment: `wire [3:0] temp = count + 1 + skip; always @(posedge clock) count <= temp >= limit ? temp - limit : temp;`

Comment: I think only person who understand the problem @DaveTweed. Thanks. Your answer is great. I will EDIT question and reply.

Comment: @DaveTweed; Is this problem can be solved without using wire or blocking assignments?

Comment: I introduced the wire just to simplify the assignment to `count` and hopefully demonstrate the logic more clearly. You can certainly write it out without using the wire. And as long as you're only making one assignment to `count`, you can use either blocking or nonblocking assignment. `always @(posedge clock) count = count + 1 + skip >= limit ? count + 1 + skip - limit : count + 1 + skip;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe it will be useful to someone.

```
module Counter(iClk, iRst, iSkip, iRev, oState);
     input iClk, iRst, iSkip, iRev;
   //declare oState:
   //declare internal wires and reg types here:
     output [3:0] oState;
     parameter [3:0] limit = 14;
     reg [4:0] temp = 5'd0;
     reg [4:0] cnt = 5'd0;
     integer skip = 1;

 always @ (posedge iClk)
 begin
  if (!iRst) begin
     
     temp = 5'd0; // to prevent overflow 5bits required
     cnt = 5'd0;
      
  end 
  else begin 
        
        if (iSkip && !iRev) begin // only iSkip asserted
            skip = 5;
        end 
        else if(!iSkip && iRev) begin // only iRev asserted
            skip = -2;
        end
        else if(iSkip && iRev) begin //iSkip and iRev asserted
            skip = 9;
        end
        else begin //Neither asserted
            skip = 1;
        end

        temp = temp + skip;
        
        if (temp > limit) begin
        cnt = temp-limit-1;
        end
        else begin
        cnt = temp;
        end
        
        temp = cnt;
            
        
  end
 end
```